# Customized PHP Excel Export

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Is anyone aware of a method to export specific fields from a database with custom column titles into excel from MSQL using PHP?

Where are there resources on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generate+excel+file+%5Bphp%5D

Comment: Must be excel format, or is CSV good enough?

Comment: must be excel unfortunetly...

Comment: a good csv would suffice for the time though

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel 2010 in Win 7 will no longer open files with the .xls extension if they are formatted as TAB-delimited text or CSV. The same files that download fine on my XP or Vista computers don't open at all on my Win7 computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel will happily read a CSV file as a spreadsheet. CSV is just a text format, so create some text and echo it with the appropriate content-type:

```
$query = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$csv = '"First Column Title","Second Column Title","Third Column Title"' . "\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $csv .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $row['col1']) . '",';
    $csv .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $row['col2']) . '",';
    $csv .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $row['col3']) . '"' . "\n";
}

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
echo $csv;
```

Comment: $csv .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $row['col1']) . '",';                   What goes in the '' marks?

Comment: Mike, I believe he is double-quoting any quotes that are in the fields because of the way .csv files use quotation marks.

Comment: That's right. Since values are enclosed in double quotes, any double quotes appearing within the value should be escaped. CSV format escapes double quotes by doubling them, i.e. turning `"` into `""`, which is what the code there does.

Comment: is $result = mysql_query($result);
supposed to be $result = mysql_query($query);
??

Comment: This now downloads as a .php file with the results inside... what could cause that?

Comment: To specify a filename... `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=something.xls");`

Answer (score 4):

Using the [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) library:

```
// connection with the database
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "database";

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// require the PHPExcel file
require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// simple query

$query = "SELECT username,emailAdress,locationCity FROM users ORDER by id DESC";
$headings = array('User Name', 'EMail Address','City');

if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
    // Create a new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List of Users');

    $rowNumber = 1;
    $col = 'A';
    foreach($headings as $heading) {
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading);
       $col++;
    }

    // Loop through the result set
    $rowNumber = 2;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $col = 'A';
       foreach($row as $cell) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
          $col++;
       }
       $rowNumber++;
    }

    // Freeze pane so that the heading line will not scroll
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');

    // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="userList.xls"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   exit();
}
echo 'a problem has occurred... no data retrieved from the database';
```

Using PHPExcel, you can also add formatting, or create workbooks with multiple worksheets, etc

Comment: +1 For PHPExcel, but keep in mind that it uses lots of resources (well, lots of memory).

Comment: @wimvds - I'm fully aware of **all** the limitations of PHPExcel... I am the developer - and there there are tricks and techniques that can be used to reduce memory and improve speed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a select on the fields you want, and output the results with fields separated by commas, and each row on its own line. Ideally, should should surround each value with quotes, and `addslashes()` to escape any quotes in the data.

Output the result and save to a file with a name ending in `.csv`, and open it in Excel.